# Question on Logic in translation

Tags: linear-algebra, logic, affine-geometry

let $P,P'$ two affine subspace of $R^{3}$

have we equality between this two statement

$$\exists\ u_{0}\in R^{3}\ \mbox{such that } t_{u_0}(P)=P'$$

$$\exists B,A\in PP' \mbox{such that  } u_{0}=\vec{BA}(=A-B) \ \mbox{ and } t_{u_0}(B)=A $$

any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Make a drawing!

Assume that $P,P'$ are two planes.  $t_{u_0}(P)=P'$ iff {$P,P'$ are parallel and there are $B\in P,A\in P'$ s.t. $u_0=\vec{BA}$}. Note that $u_0=\vec{BA}$ iff  $t_{u_0}(B)=A$. Finally the first assertion implies the second one  ; yet the converse is false.